# How to access an ArrayList from another JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, class, arraylist, jframe

How can I access multiple array lists from a `JFrame` (called `mainframe`) to another frame (called `MakeABooking`)?

I need this to get the values of the array lists to append them to a txt `File` (class `FileIO`).

```
 ArrayList <String> names = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList <String> surnames = new ArrayList<>();
```

These are the names of the array lists I need to pass to the other frame.

Comment: 1) *"another jframe"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way is to make the mainframe accessible from the MakeABooking.

When you instantiate MakeABooking, let it encapsulate the mainFrame just adding a proper constructor, e.g.

```
public MakeABooking(MainFrame mainFrame){
    this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
}
```

and calling it

```
new MakeABooking(mainFrame); // or new MakeABooking(this) from the mainFrame
```

then, from MakeABooking, when you need that you can:

```
ArrayList<String> names = mainFrame.getNames();
```

where `getNames()` is a method you wrote on the mainFrame to encapsulate the names field. e.g.,

```
public ArrayList<String> getNames(){
   return names;
}
```